# Question about the sending schedule (Warmup)

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, deliverability, ip-warming

I am doing the warmup. Can I send two emails in consecutive days or should I give a 1-day spacing?

Comment: Are you talking about sending two consecutive emails (different emails) to the same customer?

Comment: Yes, that's right

Comment: How are your campaigns planned? Are you sending to the same batch of customers each day or have you split your audience?

Comment: The campaigns are planned as follows, I have a total base and divide it based on the Salesforce warmup documentation. The email sending days were defined as Monday and Wednesday, but the customer wants to send it on Monday and Tuesday.

Comment: Remember to mark my answer as accepted if it has been helpful

Answer (score 1):

It is not uncommon during IP warmup process to switch sending days around to accommodate for more time critical sends from an existing platform. The risk of sending emails two days in a row is really dependent on how far you are in the IP warmup process. If you are just on your week 1 or 2, I would avoid it, as you are just getting noticed by the ISPs and their tolerance is not very big. Making a wrong move here is slightly more risky than if you are more than half way through the process.

That said, the success of your IP warmup is not only down to spreading your sends evenly across a week, but a combination of this, with the volumes you have, the engagement of your recipients (are you starting by sending to most engaged ones?), unsubscribes and bounces... I have been in same situation as you, and was asked to move the sendout one day. Since you have two "warmup" days in a week, I would ask your client to move the Wednesday to a later day that week, rather than sending it the day after the previous round.

Your content in the IP warmup emails should not be that time critical, as you would like to be able to send the same email across your entire audience over the course of 2-3 weeks, before continuing with a new email for following batches. It would most probably have branding/awareness content, so it is not that time critical and can easily be postponed one or two days.